# Transfer Ipython namespace to ipdb

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

I am in the middle of an ipython session. I've loaded a module `foo` which contains a function `foo.bar`. While working, I notice that `foo.bar` gives some weird output when I feed it some input `x`, where `x` is a variable in my local ipython scope. I would like to investigate the behavior in a debugger.

How would I set a breakpoint at `foo.bar` and run `foo.bar(x)` in a debugger?

I know about `pdb.set_trace()`, but it would require me to open up the code of the `foo` module to insert a breakpoint manually, save it, reload the module in ipython, etc. There has to be a better way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can use [`pdb.runcall`](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#pdb.runcall) in this case:

```
import pdb
pdb.runcall(foo.bar, x)
```